# Android- How to clone a git repo and init submodules

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, google-drive-api

I am trying to complete the Google Android Sample App - DrEdit. See link: [DrEdit Google Android App](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/android).

My question: How do I "Clone DrEdit's git repo and init submodules"? It is step 2 in the link. Please advise. I am using Eclipse. Also, I am a new to Android.

What I've tried: I've opened Eclipse, then clicked on Window->Open Perspective->Other->Git Respository Exploring->Clone a Git Repository. But I am not sure where to go or what to enter from there.

Please help.

Comment: I am trying this now... We'll see if it works: [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Repository)

Comment: I am trying this too: [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Repository).

Answer (score 1):

run the follinw in your command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/googledrive/dredit.git
cd dredit
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I guess, there are equivalent buttons in egit. But I never used it. Command line is more intuitive for git.

In the end, you need to import/create the eclipse project from the folder created above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

you've just to execute `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` after cloning your project.